# Why are mapping reductions from incomputable Languages OK?

Tags: automata, reductions

For example, many reductions from $A_{TM}$ will often have the lines:

```
Simulate M on w:
    if M accepts 
       ...
    else
```

But: a reduction is a computable function, right? So why are we allowed to say "if M accepts"?
Also, I can take the same logic and reduce $A_{TM}$ to a deciable language:
Let L be the empty language. Clearly L is decidable.

Given $(M,w)$:

```
 Output output:
      If M accepts w
            output = '0'
      else
            output = $\emptyset$
```

Obviously I'm wrong here. But why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that you are given as input "$(M,w) \in A_{TM}$". Perhaps you are given an instance $(M,w)$ of the halting problem, that is, an element of the domain of $A_{TM}$.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant, I'll fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

- Either the pseudocode means "run $A_{TM}$ on the pair $M,w$" when it says "Simulate $M$ on $w$";
- or it really means to simulate $M$ on $w$, and if it ever stops then do something; there is no "else" clause in that case.

Comment: So basically "If M accepts" should be changed to "If M ever accepts?" What if I wanted to do something in the case that M rejects? Is that possible?

Comment: You can do whatever you want once $M$ halts.

Comment: I guess my question is this: Someone asks me to give them a computable function.. I give them a function that contains "if/when M halts on W, accept x"... How is that computable?

Comment: Simple. You simulate $M$ on $w$, and if it ever halts, you do something. Otherwise, your machine also never halts.

Comment: Oh I get it now. The problem I was having was that I was thinking of giving the output only after simulating M on w, when in fact you first give M', which itself simulates M on w. Thanks :)